# Binding UWP control to code behind property

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am developing UWP app and I created new user control and I want to bind it to dependency property in the control's code behind (without the datacontext).

Code Behind:

```
public Brush Fill
{
    get { return (Brush)GetValue(FillProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FillProperty, value); }
}

// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Fill.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
public static readonly DependencyProperty FillProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Fill", typeof(Brush), typeof(MyControl), new PropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black)));
```

XAML:

```
...
<Grid>
    <Path Fill="{Binding ????}" Stretch="Fill">
        ...
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

I want that my path's fill property will bind to the property `Fill` from code behind (the data context should hold different data so I can't use it here)

How can I do that in UWP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`x:Bind`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension) would work perfectly on this. Note `x:Bind` will be looking for properties, methods & events defined in your XAML's code-behind. It's a more performant binding than `ElementName`.

```
<Path Fill="{x:Bind Fill, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the ElementName property of a binding to circumvent the data context, just as normal WPF allows you to do.

If the property is part of the user control you'll need to assign a name via x:Name to your user control in xaml to access it

```
<UserControl [...] x:Name="Control"...`
```

Then use something like`{Binding ElementName=Control, Path=Fill}`, as long as Fill is a property of your user control.